# Installing GitWeb - How to

Tags: git, gitweb

I've just installed Git on my production server and am hoping to get GitWeb working with it. I became very interested in getting it to work when I stumbled across a tutorial showing how to make git web work using...

git instaweb -d webrick --start

It works exactly as described in the tutorial at ...
http://lostechies.com/jasonmeridth/2009/09/27/git-instaweb/

However after reading other forums it seems like instaweb is not really meant to be used and instead I should set up GitWeb to run on Apache.

I am fairly new to Apache so am not very familiar with what I should be doing. I've been following the tutorial at http://unix-heaven.org/node/31 . But i don't think I need all of it. I think the only thing I need to do is put the following in my httpd.conf file...

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin <a href="mailto:admin@example.org">admin@example.org</a>
    ServerName git.example.org
    ServerAlias git-pub.example.org
    RedirectMatch ^/$ /gitweb.cgi
    SetEnv GITWEB_PROJECTROOT /cvs/codeRepository/git

    Alias /gitweb.js                /srv/www/gitweb/static/gitweb.js
    Alias /gitweb.css               /srv/www/gitweb/static/gitweb.css
    Alias /git-logo.png             /srv/www/gitweb/static/git-logo.png
    Alias /git-favicon.png           /srv/www/gitweb/static/git-favicon.png

    ScriptAlias / "/srv/www/gitweb/"

    <Directory "/srv/www/gitweb/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/httpd-git-pub.example.org-access.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/httpd-git-pub.example.org-error.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

Where /srv/www/gitweb/ contains....

```
$:/srv/www/gitweb # ls -ltr
total 252
-rwx------ 1 root root 247917 Feb 27 15:02 gitweb.cgi
drwx------ 2 root root   4096 Feb 27 15:03 static
```

Will the config I've specified above work or I need to specify ? And if so what url will I access GitWeb at? Do I need serverName, serverAlias and serverAdmin?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

The url you would use would be

```
http://git.example.org
```

But I am not so sure about your config. [Mine is simpler](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L93), and I always recommend an address like http(s)://yourServer/gitweb, instead of just  http(s)://yourServer/: if you need to add more services, you can add more root url (like `/gitweb`).

For a quick http access without authentication:

```
# GitWeb on 80
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>

  ServerName git.example.org
  ServerAlias git-pub.example.org

  SetEnv GITWEB_PROJECTROOT /cvs/codeRepository/git
  SetEnv GIT_HTTP_BACKEND "/usr/local/apps/git/libexec/git-core/git-http-backend"

  DocumentRoot /srv/www/gitweb
  Alias /gitweb /srv/www/gitweb

  <Directory /srv/www/gitweb>

    Options ExecCGI +FollowSymLinks +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AddHandler cgi-script cgi
    DirectoryIndex gitweb.cgi

  </Directory>

  BrowserMatch ".*MSIE.*" \
    nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
    downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

  LogLevel Info
  ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/gitweb_error_log"
  TransferLog "/var/log/apache2/gitweb_access_log"

</VirtualHost>
```

Note: in my [original config file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/apache/env.conf.tpl#L49-L93) (which is a template, with placeholder values like  `@PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@`), I didn't use `GITWEB_PROJECTROOT` because I am calling Gitolite, which knows where the Git repos are.

I do set a variable in the [`gitweb.conf` file](https://github.com/VonC/compileEverything/blob/master/gitweb/gitweb.conf.pl.tpl#L18-L20), though, which plays the same role than  `GITWEB_PROJECTROOT`, according to the [gitweb documentation](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/gitweb.conf.txt#L118-L145):

```
 $projectroot::
```

> Absolute filesystem path which will be prepended to project path; the path to repository is `$projectroot/$project`.
>   Set to `$GITWEB_PROJECTROOT` during installation.
>   This variable has to be set correctly for gitweb to find repositories.
>
> For example, if `$projectroot` is set to "`/srv/git`" by putting the following
>   in gitweb config file:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
our $projectroot = "/srv/git";
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

> then:

```
------------------------------------------------
http://git.example.com/gitweb.cgi?p=foo/bar.git
------------------------------------------------
```

> and its path_info based equivalent

```
------------------------------------------------
http://git.example.com/gitweb.cgi/foo/bar.git
------------------------------------------------
```

> will map to the path '/srv/git/foo/bar.git' on the filesystem.

---

Update August 2018, for Git 2.19 (Q3 2018, five years later)

"`git instaweb`" has been adjusted to run better with newer Apache on RedHat based distros.

See [commit 757b124](https://github.com/git/git/commit/757b12494bd3e4c6cbc2fd081d60ed41b60208ae) (07 Aug 2018), and [commit 1976311](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1976311aa285549599e5a451d7ad72b55a2b60e2) (08 Aug 2018) by [Sebastian Kisela (`skisela`)](https://github.com/skisela).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 93ded33](https://github.com/git/git/commit/93ded333bcb6687bc2aee533f18e5a0ea718024a), 20 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### `git-instaweb`: fix apache2 config with apache >= 2.4
>
> The generated apache2 config fails with apache >= 2.4.  The error log
>   states:
>
> ```
> AH00136: Server MUST relinquish startup privileges before accepting connections.  
> Please ensure mod_unixd or other system security module is loaded.
> AH00016: Configuration Failed
> ```
>
> **Fix this by loading the `unixd` module**.
>   This works with older `httpd` as well, so no `IfVersion` conditional is needed.  (Tested with httpd-2.2.15 on CentOS-6.)

Comment: Some questions...

Why have you omitted GITWEB_PROJECTROOT ? Is that because it is specified in gitweb.cgi using the our $projectroot definition?

    And Listen @PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@ should just be List 8080 right? My http port? Or is it a port specific to GitWeb.

Thanks again

Comment: @user1600419 I have edited my answer to add `GITWEB_PROJECTROOT` and to explain why it wasn't there in the first place. And yes, @PORT_HTTP_GITWEB@ is a placeholder value in a template file, for you to replace by the port of your choosing. I have edited the answer to replace it by (for instance) port 80.