# Cannot verify Fake email in GitHub

Tags: github

I have created a GitHub account and, I do not like sharing my email address publicly (I'm sick of Spam), so I followed GitHub's [Keeping Your Email Address Private](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private) tutorial and everything worked fine up until the point where you have to verify the fake email you created.

[image: Cannot verify Fake email on GitHub]

So how do I verify this fake email that I created on GitHub?

I did check my real email account that is associated with my GitHub account incase they sent an email there but no, I have not received anything there. Since it is a fake email address, I thought, maybe I can just click verify, but no, that doesn't work either.

Comment: GitHub recently changed how they do this. Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't verify the fake e-mail address. This is how it is suppose to work. Just go ahead and use the fake e-mail address with commits.

Update -

GitHub recently update the [Keeping Your Email Address Private](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private) tutorial. The "Hiding your email for commits on the website" section has everything you need to know, and will credit your commits to you. This way you won't have unverified e-mail addresses anymore.

Comment: The page says "You can keep your personal email address private by using username@users.noreply.github.com for commits you make in the browser or push from the command line."  I'm using the GitHub Desktop. Sure would be nice if they address that too!!!! :-/

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to verify your fake e-mail address to use it in commits and have those commits linked to your GitHub account.

You also don't have to create your own fake e-mail address. GitHub creates one for you when you turn on the "Keep my email address private" option on your [email settings](https://github.com/settings/emails). Next to your primary e-mail address, you should see a message like this:

> Because you have email privacy enabled, joe@example.com will be used for account-related notifications and joe@users.noreply.github.com will be used for web-based GitHub operations (e.g. edits and merges).

You can use that no-reply e-mail address as your fake e-mail address. See the [e-mail addresses](https://help.github.com/articles/about-commit-email-addresses/) help page for more details, including information on the new style of fake e-mail addresses that include an id number. Those addresses will continue to work if you change your GitHub account name.