# Best practice for email addresses in open source code?

Tags: github, open-source

From a security standpoint (specifically preventing email scraping), what is the best practice for email addresses in source code specifically intended for distribution on sites such as GitHub?  As an example, PHPDoc syntax for the author element includes the author's email address in plain text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a private GitHub email address: see "[Keeping your email address private](https://help.github.com/articles/keeping-your-email-address-private)", using your [GitHub account Email settings](https://github.com/settings/emails), at least for the commits (as I mentioned in "[Does Git publicly expose my e-mail address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18186072/6309)"):

[image: https://github-images.s3.amazonaws.com/help/settings/email_privacy.png]

```
git config --global user.email "username@users.noreply.github.com"
```

But for the *content* of those commits, there isn't much solution except making sure to use a custom email address dedicated for that work.

Comment: Thanks for confirming my thoughts.