# Private email addresses in Github Enterprise

Tags: git, github, github-enterprise

[This StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/897586/does-git-publicly-expose-my-e-mail-address) and [this page on the GitHub docs](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address) outline how to set up a private email address, but I do not see this option available in my Enterprise account when going to Settings --> Emails. Is this a known issue? An option selected by the owner of my Enterprise account? What's the best workaround for this? I'd like to avoid my email address being made public to spambots. Not strictly a coding question, but I would be grateful for a response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "[Setting your commit email address](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-your-github-user-account/setting-your-commit-email-address)" allows you to switch documentation between:

- github.com
- GHE (GitHub Enterprise) 3.x/2.x

You can then see if that feature is available in GHE: apparently it is not.
This is not listed in [GHE release notes](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@3.0/admin/release-notes).

A workaround would then be to use a dedicated email address for that usage.